# scrape multiple web pages with unchanging url by clicking next

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape multiple pages from https://ethnicelebs.com/all-celebs this website but the url for each page remains the same. I want to scrape ethnicity information of all characters from all pages (when click at the name listed).

After navigating, I used the following code to scrape ethnicity information but it kept scraping the first page:

```py
url = 'https://ethnicelebs.com/all-celeb'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
while True:

    page = requests.post(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for href in soup.find_all('a', href=True)[18:]:
        print('Found the URL:{}'.format(href['href']))
        request_href = requests.get(href['href'])
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(request_href.content)
        for each in soup2.find_all('strong')[:-1]:
            print(each.text)

    Next_button = (By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Go to next page']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Next_button)).click()
    url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(5)
```

(Thanks to @Sureshmani!)

How can I scrape the current page while it keeps navigating instead of keeping back to the first page? Thanks!

Comment: what info are you trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to navigate to each page using this approach,

```
    url = 'https://ethnicelebs.com/all-celeb'
  driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
i = 1
while i<52:
    myxpath = "//div[contains(@data-id,'pt-cv-page-"+str(i)+"')]//h6/a"
    print(myxpath)
    CelebLinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(myxpath)
    print('Total Celeb displayed in the current page', len(CelebLinks))
    for links in CelebLinks:
        print(str(links.text).encode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))
        print('Link URl: ',links.get_attribute('href'))
        request_href = requests.get(links.get_attribute('href'))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request_href.content)
        for each in soup.find_all('strong')[:-1]:
            print(str(each.text).encode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))
    Next_button = (By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Go to next page']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Next_button)).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    i+=1
    continue
```

You will need following imports

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to scrape all ethnicity information of each character(when you click each name listed) for all pages, but my code kept scraping all names and information of the first page, do you mind pointing out the problems and how I fix that?

Comment: @elaine please edit the orginal question and add your code & expected behavior.

Comment: @elaine Updated the code for your ask. check & let me know. If it serves the purpose, request you to upvote the answer. thanks!

Comment: it did work thank you so much!!!!!! I tried to upvote your answer several times but system only recorded the upvote without showing it as I'm new to this community and have less than 15 reputation points. sorry about that but thank you so much for your help!